# How do I get the index of the selected item in a Combobox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

In a `Combobox`, I would need to get not the contents of the selected item but the index (or position) of the line or selected item.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`current`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Combobox.html) method. Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


r = tk.Tk()

c = ttk.Combobox(r)
c["values"] = ["first", "second", "third"]
c.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda _ : print(c.current()))
c.current(0)
c.pack()

r.mainloop()
```